# http:// to https:// returns 100+ errors in console

Tags: javascript, security, http, https, console

I've implemented a Bright Cove video to an https:// secured website, but the console throws a TON of errors with "http://" related URLs. They're all outside URLS that I can't customize to be "https://"

Does anyone know how to fix something like this? The video loads in just fine, but I feel like having a ton of errors in the console is never good.

Here's the URL for reference.

https://dmsymphony.org/press/video-registers-michael-morain-interrogates-joseph-giunta/

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Link doesn't appear to be publicly accessible

Comment: @steven Touché! That was the "preview" link. I changed it to the public view - thanks for the heads up

Comment: You're loading insecure (http://) content from a secure (http://) page; that's what browsers do when that happens, because it's a security risk.

Comment: The link you provided has auto playing video. I'm not sure I even want to help you :)

Comment: @Pointy Is there a way to target those outside links, though? My snippet of code for the video is all "https://" but I'm thinking one of those URLs is calling outside sources that I'm unable to target & change to be "https://"

Comment: @steven Haha, I know. Not my preferred choice of video play, we were just asked to put this on their page!

Comment: @alliefayden well the right way to do it would be to have the links be "https://" links. You can't tell the browser not to issue the warnings, and some people's browsers may not load that content at all (that is, in addition to the warning, the content won't be loaded).

Comment: http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/publishing-video-cloud-player-https-page